# Access method available to struct used in type declaration

Tags: go

Is it possible to access methods that are declared in a type's underlying type? For example, I want a `ResourceSet` to be able to call my `Set` type's `AddId` method .

See: http://play.golang.org/p/Fcg6Ryzb67

```
package main

type Resource struct { 
  Id uint32
}

type Set map[uint32]struct{}

func (s Set) AddId(id uint32) {
  s[id] = struct{}{}
}

type ResourceSet Set

func (s ResourceSet) Add(resource Resource) {
  id := resource.Id
  s.AddId(id)
}

func main() {
  resource := Resource{Id: 1}

  s := ResourceSet{}
  s.Add(resource)
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
s.AddId undefined (type ResourceSet has no field or method AddId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a new named type is to have a fresh and empty method set.

Embedding is a different story and add some syntactical sugar to call methods of embedded types.

Comment: Ok, that's useful to know. So what's the point then? What's a use case?

Comment: @Wec: The use case is: You want a type with a special method set but you can represent the types state in an other named type (whose method has methods you do not want your type to have).

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using [embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding):

```
type ResourceSet struct {
  Set
}

func (s ResourceSet) Add(resource Resource) {
  id := resource.Id
  s.AddId(id)
}

func main() {
  resource := Resource{Id: 1}

  s := ResourceSet{Set{}}
  s.Add(resource)
}
```

You can also create an [initializing constructor](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals) to make the `ResourceSet` creation process simpler:

```
func NewResourceSet() {
  return ResourceSet{Set{}}
}

func main() {
  s := NewResourceSet()
}
```